# handles a control in a formview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, formview, handles

How can I do a handles from a control contened in a formview,  in code only i can see formview but not the controls in the inserttemplate.

thank for any help

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the FindControl method to find a control.

```
TextBox txtEmail = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ControldID");
```

This is because the controls that are in the DataBound Controls are not directly accessible. To Access these controls, you have to use the `FindControl` method and cast it in appropriate control.