# Object reference not set to an instance of an object at line if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdcd.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdrcd.Text))

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, code-behind

```
 protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tdcd = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_COMPL_DATETextBox");
        TextBox tdrcd = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_REVIEW_COMPL_DATETextBox");
        RadioButtonList rbl =(RadioButtonList)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList");
        TextBox tll = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_COMMENTSTextBox");

        //if (!"".Equals(tdcd) && !"".Equals(tdrcd))

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdcd.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdrcd.Text))
        {

            //tdcd.Visible = true;
            //tdrcd.Visible = true;

            FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList").Visible = true;
            FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_COMMENTSTextBox").Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //tdcd.Visible = false;
            //tdrcd.Visible = false;
            FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList").Visible = false;
            FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_COMMENTSTextBox").Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object at line

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdcd.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdrcd.Text))
```

Comment: Beautiful naming conventions...

Comment: In which `ItemTemplate` are those TextBoxes? You would normally use `FormView.ItemDataBound` with the appropriate `FormViewMode` (check the [`CurrentMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode%28v=vs.100%29) property of the `FormView`).

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357746/how-to-hide-or-disable-radiobuttonlist-and-textbox-based-on-condition-of-another

Answer (score 1):

Your `tdcd` or `tdrcd` is null. That is why you are getting this exception. You may check them first for the null.

```
if ((tdcd != null && tdrcd!=null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdcd.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tdrcd.Text)))
```

Comment: Showing the same error at line FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList").Visible = false;

Comment: You are not finding the control properly. Make sure you right spellings for the controls, also what is FormViewDiagnostic ?

Comment: FormViewDiagnostic is form_id. All the textboxes and radiobuttonlist are in edititemtemplate in ForView

Answer (score 1):

`tdcd` or `tdrcd` is `null` as your searching it and it is not guaranteed that you will always get it.

```
TextBox tdcd = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_COMPL_DATETextBox");
TextBox tdrcd = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_REVIEW_COMPL_DATETextBox");
```

Answer (score 1):

`tdcd` or `tdrcd` is null. Which means `FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl()` is returning null for one of them.

This probably means either `"DIAG_COMPL_DATETextBox"` or `"DIAG_REVIEW_COMPL_DATETextBox"` is not the correct ID of the control.

Check those IDs match up to what's actually declared on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check like this

```
if(tdcd != null && tdrcd != null)
{
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` references(`tdcd` and/or `tdrcd`)  are null.

You should use the `FormView.ItemDataBound` event with the appropriate `FormViewMode` (check the [`CurrentMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode%28v=vs.100%29) property of the `FormView`) to get a reference to your controls.

You also need to `DataBind` the FormView previously, what creates the controls.

For example (asuming that the`TextBoxes` are in The `EditItemTenmplate`):

```
protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object someSource=null;
    FormViewDiagnostic.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    FormViewDiagnostic.DataSource = someSource;
    FormViewDiagnostic.DataBind();
}


protected void FormViewDiagnostic_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var view = (FormView)sender;
    if (view.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        var txt1 = (TextBox)view.FindControl("DIAG_COMPL_DATETextBox");
        var txt2 = (TextBox)view.FindControl("DIAG_REVIEW_COMPL_DATETextBox");
        var txt3 = (TextBox)view.FindControl("DIAG_LL_COMMENTSTextBox");
        var rbl = (RadioButtonList)view.FindControl("DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList");
        txt3.Enabled = rbl.Enabled = txt1.Text.Length != 0 && txt2.Text.Length != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to disable radiobuttonlist and textbox3 if textbox 1 and textbox 2 are empty

Comment: protected void FormViewDiagnostic_DataBound(Object sender,EventArgs e)
 {    
   if (FormViewDiagnostic.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)   
  {     
        var tb1 = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_COMPL_DATETextBox");             
                var tb2= (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_REVIEW_COMPL_DATETextBox");
                var rb1 = (RadioButtonList)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList");
                var tb3 = (TextBox)FormViewDiagnostic.FindControl("DIAG_LL_COMMENTSTextBox");                  
            }
        }

Comment: protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Object someSource = null; 
            FormViewDiagnostic.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit); 
            FormViewDiagnostic.DataSource = someSource; 
            FormViewDiagnostic.DataBind(); }

Comment: Now I able to hide the control alone but label is visible

Comment: @Viswa: I have showed how to disable the controls as requested, to hide them you need to set the `Visible` property instead of the `Enabled` property. I have no clue what label you want to hide.

Comment: <EditItemTemplate>
<tr><td> Approval</td><td width="25%">
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="DIAG_LL_APPROVALRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Text='<%# Bind("DIAG_LL_APPROVAL") %>'>                 <asp:ListItem>Approved</asp:ListItem>      <asp:ListItem>Rejected</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Selected="True">None</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
 </td> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>Comments </td> <td> <asp:TextBox ID="DIAG_LL_COMMENTSTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DIAG_LL_COMMENTS") %>' MaxLength="1000" /></td></tr></table></EditItemTemplate>

Comment: @Viswa: You should either edit your question and post that aspx markup or try to put it in plain language to explain me what you're trying to achieve. You cannot expect me to interpret these comments. Apart from that, **there is no label in your `EditItemTemplate`**.