# Inserting value into sql server: control not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Title sounds pretty plain, but here are the specifics.

I was handed an old website to extend a little. It is a VB.NET implementation, and it was the original coder's first site - so lots of attaboys at getting it to work.

**Summary of site:**
Master page design, with oAuth login page. Main page is a pagination of the records, and based on if the user has logged on or not, a separate button is displayed to edit. So far - not that big a deal, it works, all good.

Now when we delve into the edit page, the product owner wants to be able to add a note to to the record.  Seems pretty easy, all the other CRUD is completed, except the actual inserting.

I've added a textarea at the bottom of the page, and a push button. The insert event is working, and dummy records are being placed into the database.

But the failure comes into play when I try to get the value of the textarea, to put into the query.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script language="VB" runat="server" >
Protected Sub NewNoteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  '    Dim myStringResult As String = NewNoteTextArea.InnerHtml
MsgBox("Here1")
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("XXXXXConnectionString").ConnectionString
Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
  Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EasementNote ([RE_Number], [noteuser], [note]) VALUES (@RE_Number, @NoteUser, @Note)")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RE_Number", "test")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoteUser", "test")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", "more testing")
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
  End Using
End Using
MsgBox("here2")
End Sub
</script>    
 <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
 </head>
```

Here is where I have the HTML code

```
  <asp:TableFooterRow Width="100%">
    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="center" ColumnSpan="2">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />&nbsp;
      <asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="center" ColumnSpan="1">
      <asp:TextBox id="NewNoteTextArea" TextMode="multiline" Columns="40" Rows="3" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="NewNoteButton" Text="Insert Note" OnClick="NewNoteButton_Click"/>
    </asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableFooterRow>
```

When I try to grab the value of the textarea, I am receiving a

[image: Error message]

I am truly stumped on why I am getting this error message. BTW - there is no code behind page... not sure why, but there isn't, but when I added one, and moved the button click event to it, the button click could not resolve.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Being inside a server control should it not be referred with FindControl such as in this case http://forums.asp.net/post/4479665.aspx

Comment: The FindControl also fails with the 'is not declared' error.

Comment: Looking at your code and comments it seems that your TextBox is in a Table (server control) which in turn is inside a FormView. If it is so then you will have to follow the same hierarchy using FindControl such as FormView > Table > FooterRow > Cell > TextBox as in the asp.net forum link given above (Check multiple FindControl)

Comment: haraman - Please post as an answer, so you get the points.   Here is what worked...  Dim TextBoxText As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.FormView1.FindControl("NewNoteTextArea"), TextBox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your control is inside another server control you need to use FindControl to access that in the code such as

```
Dim txtNote As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.FormView1.FindControl("NewNoteTextArea"), TextBox)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) property value of the textbox control, not InnerHtml

```
Dime mySyting as String = NewNoteTextArea.Text
```

Comment: @pithhelmet Is your Textbox inside your form tag ? Also Is this code in the  code behind file of the same page ?

Comment: It is buried within a asp:FormView    and all the true 'code' is on the same page, and yes, all the templates reside within a FORM element, but the sub is outside of the form element

Comment: @pithhelmet In that case you must read this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/4476186/5104101